# Create and fill each list within a list

Tags: python, list

I learned to create and manage nested lists by building a NxM matrix and filling it with random integers.

I've solved it via a simple one-liner and struggled to write a comprehensive solution.

I call the first solution as a cheating because I got this tip from this website, but didn't completely understand how it works. So, I've tried to write a more detailed piece of code on my own, which was difficult, and I'm not completely sure I got it right.

The original solution:

```
from random import randint

size_n = int(input("Number of lists N "))
size_m = int(input("Number of elements M "))

matrix = [[randint(1,9) for m in range(size_m)] for n in range(size_n)]
print(matrix)
```

I had a hard time to create a list of list with the correct levels of loops in loops. I end up with the temporary matrix, but I'm not sure it's good solution.

The final solution:

```
from random import randint

size_n = int(input("Number of lists N "))
size_m = int(input("Number of elements M "))
matrix = []

for n in range(size_n):
    tmp = []
    for m in range(size_m):
        tmp.append(randint(1,9))
    matrix.append(tmp)

print(matrix)
```

Can you help me to understand what is the correct solution for the task?

P.S. Is it normal for developer to look for another solution if the code just works but you think it might be prettier?

Comment: What's cheating about list comprehensions? And to answer your other question, whether it's normal or not, I don't think it's wrong to search for more elegant solutions.

Comment: What's wrong with your original solution?

Comment: I got this tip from this website, but didn't completely understand how it works. So, I've tried to write a more detailed piece of code on my own, which was difficult, and I'm not completely sure I got it right.

Comment: Your second attempt accomplishes the same thing as the first, but with traditional loops instead of a comprehension. It's not any more "detailed" (whatever that means). It's just vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: "Is it normal for developer to look for another solution if the code just works but you think it might be prettier?" Yes, it's normal and it is an important activity. It even has a name: [Refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [[randint(1,9) for m in range(size_m)] for n in range(size_n)]
```

Let's say our `size_n` is `5`, for an example. Then `range(size_n)` gives

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

E. g. a list of 5 consecutive integers starting with 0. If you do something for each element of the list, that creates another list of the same size, for example:

```
>>>[88 for n in range(size_n)]
[88, 88, 88, 88, 88]
```

You are, of course, not limited by simple numbers, you can create, basically, anything. For example, empty lists:

```
>>>[[] for n in range(size_n)]
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

Then, of course, the inner lists don't have to be empty, you can populate them with numbers:

```
>>>[[1, 2, 3] for n in range(size_n)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Or you can use another `range` expression inside:

```
>>> [[range(1, 4)] for n in range(5)]
[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]]]
```

And you can use list comprehension on those inner lists just the same way:

```
>>> [[randint(1, 9) for m in range(1, 4)] for n in range(5)]
[[8, 4, 3], [6, 7, 2], [6, 8, 2], [9, 6, 1], [9, 1, 2]]
```

You can go deeper and deeper until you're bored or out of memory:

```
>>> [[[randint(1, 9) for n in range(1, 5)] for n in range(1, 4)] for n in range(5)]
[[[2, 9, 6, 1], [6, 7, 4, 5], [5, 9, 1, 7]], [[5, 2, 9, 3], [1, 8, 9, 7], [8, 4, 4, 8]], [[4, 4, 7, 9], [7, 1, 4, 2], [7, 8, 7, 3]], [[4, 4, 9, 9], [8, 8, 9, 5], [6, 1, 3, 9]], [[5, 9, 3, 2], [7, 5, 4, 7], [7, 7, 4, 3]]]
```

Nested list comprehension is usually the right solution, they are easy to read once you get used to the notation. Nested loops are OK too.

There's nothing wrong with looking for better ways to re-write your working code (I'd say, rather, it's wrong not to look), unless you develop an unhealthy obsession with it.

*For Python 3 `range(5)` actually doesn't give `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` directly, but for this task it's effectively the same thing.*